# wxFormBuilder component class minimized

Tags: python, windows, wxpython, wxformbuilder

This is on a windows computer.
Essentially, the component tree doesn't expand when I click on any of the options, thus, I can't create forms or do anything really that doesn't require me to hardcode this stuff myself.
Please forgive me if it's a really simple fix, I've just gotten into GUIs.

[In this picture I've circled the minimized part. Any help on how to expand it would be greatly appreciated.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kfgPk.png)